# Prior Predictive Distribution for hierarchical model

Tags: distributions, prior, hierarchical-bayesian

What I need to do is figure out the prior predictive distribution for the following mixed model: $$\begin{align*}
y_{ij} & \sim \mathsf{Normal}(\alpha_j + \beta x_i, \sigma^2)\\
\alpha_j & \sim \mathsf{Normal}(\gamma_0 + \gamma_1 u_j, \tau^2)\\
\beta, \gamma_0, \gamma_1 & \sim \mathsf{Normal}(0, \theta)\\
\sigma, \tau & \sim \mathsf{Normal}(0, \phi).
\end{align*}$$ The levels are $j$-state and $i$-house. So, $y_{ij}$ is a log valued measurement for house $i$ in county $j$. The $x_i$ is the floor tested of house $i$ taking a value of $0$ or $1$ and the $u_j$ is the log valued measurement of the county $j$. We are asked to choose appropriate values for $\theta$ and $\phi.$ To check that they are appropriate I am to sample from the prior predictive distribution. I would like to see, analytically, how we find the prior predictive distribution. I know, from the marginal probability that $$p\left(\overset{\sim}{y}\right) = \int p\left(\overset{\sim}{y}\mid \alpha_j, \beta, \sigma^2\right)p(\alpha_j, \beta, \sigma^2).$$ Where I'm stuck is unpacking the probabilities in the integrand due to the hierarchy of parameters.

edit: Clarity.

Comment: What is $\mathsf{N}$? is it normal distribution?? usually Inverse gamma distribution used for variance parameters!! also by definition $\sigma$ is positive root of $\sigma^2$ so this is not standard!

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how this gets incorporated into the prior predictive distribution.

Comment: $\sigma^2\sim Inv-Gamma(a_1,b_1)$ and $\tau^2\sim Inv-Gamma(a_2,b_2)$ are make sense. $a_i$ and $b_i$ are hyper parameters. there are some methods to deal with hyper parameters.  as an example some times use $\sigma^2\sim Inv-Gamma(.01,.01)$ this give you a flat prior

Comment: Okay. I think I understand.